# Как поменять цветовую тему не через параметры?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

Я зашел в настройки, Средства > Параметры, и хочу поменять цветовую тема, но она тупо заблокирована, по умолчанию просто стоит высокая контрастность

Comment: Я обыскал все все форумы, все они гласят что нужно поменять лишь через параметры, у меня она конечно заблокирована, я даже пытался переустанавливать, но она даже у меня не спрашивала какие параметры ставить перед запуском, попробовал скачать нужные цветовые темы, они также не конали, у меня ведь основной заблокирован), еще кстати у меня не работают цвета для шрифтов

Comment: она - кто? Версия какая студии, редакция?

Comment: Причём тут вообще C#?

Comment: версия 4.8.03752 с официального сайта Microsoft